# Install Oracle on Raspberry

Tags: raspbian, pi-3b+, debian, database

0

I need help!!

I'm doing a school project where we have to install Oracle on our Rapberry pi 3.

We have already download from Oracle website

Basic Package(RPM) -SQL*Plus Package(RPM) -SDK Package(RPM)
And from this part we don't know how to contiue, we try several ways and all of them failed.

[image: That's the last thing we wrote and now we don't know how to proceed]

What we try now is this, I take it from a website:

Everything as "root"

The repository:

echo deb http://oss.oracle.com/debian unstable main non-free >> /etc/apt/sources.list
Install the package:

apt-get install apt-transport-https
Create users and needed groups:

addgroup --system oinstall

addgroup --system dba

adduser --system --ingroup oinstall -shell /bin/bash oracle

adduser oracle dba

Create file:

nano /etc/sysctl.d/local-oracle.conf

fs.file-max = 65536

fs.aio-max-nr = 1048576

kernel.sem = 250 32000 100 128

kernel.shmmax = 2147483648

kernel.shmall = 2097152

kernel.shmmni = 4096

net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 104 65000

vm.hugetlb_shm_group = “introduce the GID of dba group”

vm.nr_hugepages = 64

sysctl configuration:

sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.d/local-oracle.conf
create a file with parameters:

nano /etc/security/limits.conf
oracle soft nproc 2047 oracle hard nproc 16384 oracle soft nofile 1024 oracle hard nofile 65536 oracle soft memlock 204800 oracle hard memlock 204800

links:

ln -s /usr/bin/awk /bin/awk

ln -s /usr/bin/basename /bin/basename

ln -s /usr/bin/rpm /bin/rpm

ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/lib64

Create needed repositories:

mkdir -p /opt/oracle/product/12.1.0.2

mkdir -p /opt/oraInventory

chown -R oracle:dba /opt/oracle/

chown -R oracle:dba /opt/oraInventory

Till this part we didn't have any problem but when I try to execute the next command: apt-get install build-essential binutils libcap-dev gcc g++ libc6-dev ksh libaio-dev make libxi-dev libxtst-dev libxau-dev libxcb1-dev sysstat rpm xauth unzip

and them move the it : mv linuxamd64_12102_database_1of2.zip /home/oracle/

Is the part were we have errors.

Thans in advance!

Comment: The Raspberry Pi is based on Debian.  Debian uses deb packages not rpm.  Why do you think Oracle will work on a Pi?

Comment: The Raspberry Pi is `armhf` or `aarch64` - why do you think an `i386` RPM would work even if DebIan supported it? It won't run on the hardware.

Answer (score 1):

It's sometimes possible to extract and use the software in an .rpm on a Debian derived system (like Raspbian/RpiOS), but not always.  The tool for extracting the content is `rpm2cpio`, which you can `apt install` and read about online (it converts the rpm to a cpio format, which can be read with `cpio`).

However, the binary architecture has to be the same.  But those are for i386 (aka x86), which will never work.  You need "armhf" or "aarch64" (aka arm64) packages.  It looks to me like probably only the latter exists:

https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-arm-aarch64-downloads.html

Which means you will have to be using the 64-bit version of RpiOS just to try this (and I cannot promise it will work).